# how to remove extra spaces in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I want to remove extra spaces from the text, i referenced the code from the internet as below:

```
(text as text)=>
let 
x = Text.Split(text," "),
y = Text.Select(x,each _<>""),
z = Text.Combine(y," ")
in 
z
```

when i apply this function for my data , it show the error is "Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Text." , my column is definitely is text format already , i don't know root of the issue, could you please help look ?
my data is very simple, like below:

[image: data]

[image: add column with using clean extra spaces]

[image: the error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [below code](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/10/08/clean-whitespace-in-powerquery/) as a custom function:

```
(text as text, optional char_to_trim as text) =>
let
   char = if char_to_trim = null then " " else char_to_trim,
   split = Text.Split(text, char),
   removeblanks = List.Select(split, each _ <> ""),
   result=Text.Combine(removeblanks, char)
in
   result
```